# How does Text("Hello") display font color when I use Jetpack Compose with default settings?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I create a project with the wizard *Empty Compose Activity* of Android Studio. I use `Text("Hello")` to display a text.

I know the font size of the text is `16.sp` by looking source code, but how can I know which color is displayed of the text?

BTW, I look at the source code , the color of font is specified as `Color.Unspecified`, I don't know what color will be displayed for `Color.Unspecified`.

**Source Code**

```
// Set of Material typography styles to start with
val Typography = Typography(
    body1 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 16.sp
    )
    ...
)


class TextStyle
@OptIn(ExperimentalTextApi::class)
internal constructor(
    ...
) {
    ...
    @OptIn(ExperimentalTextApi::class)
    constructor(
        color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
        fontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    ...
}


val Unspecified = Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, ColorSpaces.Unspecified)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color in the `Text` is defined by the `color` parameter or applying a `TextStyle`. The default value is [**`Color.Unspecified`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Color.Companion#Unspecified()).
If color = `Color.Unspecified` and style has no color set, this will be [**`LocalContentColor`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#LocalContentColor()) which provides a default [**`Color.Black`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Color.Companion#Black())  color if not specified.

Comment: Thanks! I have searched the default color is `Color.Black` for `LocalContentColor`

Comment: I don't know why Android Studio need to design so complex architecture. If I do it, the default font color of Text is `Color.Black`  and user can overwrite it.

Answer (score 2):

If we look at the source code of `Text` composable, we can find,

```
val textColor = color.takeOrElse {
    style.color.takeOrElse {
        LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = LocalContentAlpha.current)
    }
}
```

1. Here `color` is the argument passed to the `Text` composable, which defaults to `Color.Unspecified` if no `color` is passed.

We see a method `takeOrElse` is used.

**`takeOrElse` definition**

```
inline fun Color.takeOrElse(block: () -> Color): Color = if (isSpecified) this else block()
```

**`Color.isSpecified` definition**

```
inline val Color.isSpecified: Boolean get() = value != Color.Unspecified.value
```

In other words, we can read this code as set `textColor` as the `color` if it is not equal to `Color.Unspecified`, else use the value in the given lambda.

Since we already know the color is `Color.Unspecified` if no `color` is specified (from above point 1), the value in the lambda will be used.

#### Value in lambda

The lambda checks if there is a `color` in the `style` TextStyle provided (either by user or by default value `LocalTextStyle.current`). If there is one, it will be used. Else the value of the below will be used.

```
LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = LocalContentAlpha.current)
```

---

`LocalContentColor`, `LocalContentAlpha` and `LocalTextStyle` are provided using `CompositionLocalProvider`.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find the details about `LocalTextStyle.current` ? so I can know such as font size, font color, and so on.

Comment: All the local components `LocalTextStyle`, `LocalContentColor`, etc. vary according to their composable. If called from Button you might get a different value than when called from Scaffold body. The easiest way to determine the value is to either create a variable and use a debugger or log the values.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers explain which color is interpreted when `color` is `Color.Unspecified` (which is `LocalContentColor.current`), I will answer why there is a `Color.Unspecified` instead of `Color.Transparent`

Because `Color` is an inline class, this represents an unset value without having to [box](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/autoboxing-done-right-how-by-using-to-functions/8927) the `Color` object. It will be treated as **Transparent** when drawn. A `Color` object can be compared with **Color.Unspecified** for equality check, or the property `isUnspecified` of the object can be used to check for the unset value (or `Color#isSpecified` for any color that isn't `Color.Unspecified`).

This approach is used with `Offset.Unspecified`, `Size.Unspecified` and other classes that have an equivalent 'Unspecified' field for equality checks.

> I don't know what color will be displayed for Color.Unspecified.

If you need to get the color dynamically at runtime, for example if you dynamically set colors and need them to change based on their current color you can use

```
Text("Hello World",
    onTextLayout = {
        it.layoutInput.style.color
    }
)
```

Which will return

[image]

And if you assign a `Color`

```
Text("Hello World",
    color = Color.Red,
    onTextLayout = {
        it.layoutInput.style.color
    }
)
```

[image]